# What's the function or meaning of "a second time for it to select a margin"

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context

> Therefore the Court **remands this matter to Commerce** *a second time for
>   it to select a margin* that is “a reasonably accurate estimate of the
>   respondent’s actual rate, albeit with some built in increase intended
>   as a deterrent to noncompliance.”

quoted from Decisions of the United States Court of International Trade.

I'm curious about the sentence's structure.

I understand the meaning of phrase "The court remands A to B"

However, I'm not sure how "a second time for it to select a margin" fits into the sentence above.
It is like "The court remands A to B C" and it looks weird to me (nevertheless I can still interpret the sentence)

What's the function of "a second time for it to select a margin" in the sentence above and is it grammatically correct?

Comment: A link to the original article would be helpful.

Comment: *for a second time* and *for it to select a margin* are separate phrases. Think of it this way: the Court remands the matter to Commerce. The Court remands the matter to Commerce *for a second time.* The Court remands the matter to Commerce *so that Commerce can select a margin*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the Court has previously remanded the matter to Commerce and it now remands the matter to Commerce for a second time. Further, the Court expects Commerce to select a margin of the type specified.

It may or may not be that the Court gave this particular instruction when it first remanded the matter.

It's grammatical.

*. . . [A] second time for it to select a margin* might be called an adverbial in some grammars. Its purpose is to provide information about how and why the matter was remanded.